# Leer archivos en python

Tags: python, c

necesito leer un archivo en python y buscar las palabras que terminen con ing en el mismo. Ya había hecho mi código en C y funcionaba, ahora al pasarlo a python me encuentro con el problema de que no puedo leer el archivo. Espero puedan ayudarme

```
    def lecturaArchivo():
estado = 0
caracteres = []
ap = id(caracteres)
archivo = open("Archivo.txt")
salida = open("SalidaIng.txt","w+")

caracteres = archivo.read()

for ap in caracteres:
    if ap == 'i' and estado == 0:
        salida.write("Estado:")
        salida.write(str(estado))
        salida.write("\nLetra:")
        salida.write(str(ap))
        salida.write("\n\n")
        impresion(ap,estado)
        estado = 1
    elif ap == 'n' and estado == 1:
        salida.write("Estado:")
        salida.write(str(estado))
        salida.write("\nLetra:")
        salida.write(str(ap))
        salida.write("\n\n")
        impresion(ap,estado)
        estado = 2
    elif ap == 'g' and estado == 2 and caracteres[i+1] == ' ':
        salida.write("Estado:")
        salida.write(str(estado))
        salida.write("\nLetra:")
        salida.write(str(ap))
        salida.write("\n\n")
        impresion(ap,estado)

    elif ap == 'g' and estado == 2 and caracteres[i+1] !=' ':
        salida.write("Estado:")
        salida.write(str(estado))
        salida.write("\nLetra:")
        salida.write(str(ap))
        salida.write("\n\n")
        impresion(ap,estado)
        estado = 0

    elif ap == ' ':
        salida.write("Estado:")
        salida.write(str(estado))
        salida.write("\nLetra:")
        salida.write(str(ap))
        salida.write("\n\n")
        impresion(ap, estado)
        estado = 0
    else:
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap,estado)
            estado = 0
ap = id(caracteres[i+1])
```

Comment: Cual es el problema que tienes exactamente? Lo único que yo veo es que la variable `i` no esta definida.

Comment: El error como comenta wallek es que `i` no esta definida, suponiendo que sea el indice del carácter actual lo podrías arreglar con `for i, ap in enumerate(caracteres)`. Por otro lado, no se que es `ap` ni que intentas hacer con esta variable usando `id`... Eso si, si no tienes buenas razones para ello traducir C a Python literalmente no tiene sentido, conseguir la lista de palabras terminadas en ing se puede hacer con dos lineas de código en Python usando `re.findall` o `str.split` incluso. Explica el error, un poco la idea del código (como lo de ap) e identa el código correctamente. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo general cuando abris un archivo es recomendable usar el estamento [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), ya que este se encarga de abrir y cerrar el archivo automaticamente. También podes usar el slice para saber si una palabra termina con `ing`. Slice te permite decidir desde donde y hasta donde querés de un string utilizando el signo `:` y permite usar numeros negativos para contar desde atrás. Entonces una manera sencilla de hacer lo que pides es la siguiente:

```
with open('Archivo.txt') as f:
    palabras_con_ing = []
    for line in f:
        words = line.split(" ")
        for word in words:
           if 'ing' == word[-3:]:
              palabras_con_ing.append(word)

print(palabras_con_ing)
```